# Finding field.value in JSON array

Tags: javascript, json

```
var x = [{ a: 1, b: 2}, { a: 11, b: 12}, { a: 31, b: 23}, { a: 51, b: 24}]
```

how do you find `a = 11` ?

for simple arrays one can do `x.indexOf('1');` so perhaps the solution should be something like

```
var a1 = x.indexOf({a: 1});
```

ofcourse, I want to obtain the entire JSON for which the value matches.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/array-containsobj-in-javascript

Comment: This is not JSON. It's an array of plain objects. Also, I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have built-in support for object querying like you're expecting. Though, there may be libraries that can add it. But, `indexOf()` searches with `===`, which for `Object`s requires they be the exact same object; not just similar.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski thanks. thats what i wanted to know. I can now look at both recommended solution of writing code or using underscore lib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[Array.Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** with shim support on older browsers.

```
var x = [{
    a: 1,
    b: 2
}, {
    a: 11,
    b: 12
}, {
    a: 31,
    b: 23
}, {
    a: 51,
    b: 24
}],
tocomp = 11;
var res = x.filter(function (ob) { 
    return ob.a === tocomp;
});
```

Result will be array of object that matches the condition.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8mWuD/)**

And if you just care for single match and get back the matched object just use a for loop.

```
var x = [{
    a: 1,
    b: 2
}, {
    a: 11,
    b: 12
}, {
    a: 31,
    b: 23
}, {
    a: 51,
    b: 24
}],
tocomp = 11, i, match;
for (i=0, l=x.length; i<l; i++){
    if(x[i].a === tocomp){
        match = x[i];
        break; //break after finding the match
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you can do it with a simple function, no third party modules needed:

```
var x = [{ a: 1, b: 2}, { a: 11, b: 12}, { a: 31, b: 23}, { a: 51, b: 24}];

function getIndexOf(value){
    for(var i=0; i<x.lengh; i++){
        if(x[i].a == value)
            return i;
    }
}

alert(getIndexOf(value)); // output is: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply iterate over the array to get the value.

```
for(var i = 0;i < x.length; i++){
   alert(x[i].a);
}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/66rKk/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use native js or you can use underscoreJS lib.
[UnderscoreJS](http://underscorejs.org/)